# iPhone device font

Tags: iphone, ios, air, fonts

We are having issues with our embedded Telex font due to the different languages characters. From what I've read there is a **Helvetica device font** available for iPhone that should handle more/most characters.

This is what I did but no text is showing up.

```
private var defaultFormat:TextFormat;
defaultFormat = new TextFormat();
defaultFormat.font = "Helvetica";

var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.height = 40;
textField.defaultTextFormat = defaultFormat;
```

Could someone please point me into the right direction?

Comment: That doesn't look like Objective-C to me. Helvetica is the default, you shouldn't have to specify the typeface. That being said, try using "System" instead of "Helvetica"

Comment: font availability on iOS devices can be found at http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Thanks both. Indeed I am not using Objective-C but using Adobe Air and Actionscript for the app. Should have mentioned that. 

I tried "System" instead of "Helvetica" but still no text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is nothing wrong with the above code. My problem was that I was  setting the

```
textField.embedFonts = true
```

later on in the code which is **wrong**.

Note that the default is false. So, after I removed that line, my text showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe AIR uses its own Flash runtime and also provides its own text rendering. It is therefore probably not compatible with some aspects of the native rendering, like Emoji.

The default font in iOS for screens with Retina devices is Helvetica Neue which should be available as "Helvetica Neue" or "HelveticaNeue", although I'm not familiar with how the Flash Actionscript API does font naming. Cocoa knows to alias "Helvetica" to "Helvetica Neue" in some circumstances, so maybe the actual Helvetica font is unavailable, leading to your missing text.

iOS and OS X font rendering as a rule fall back to other fonts to successfully render characters and glyphs that are not available in the current font. It is possible that Flash does not do this.

Comment: Thanks Jesper for pointing me into the right direction. Figured it out